# Sql query to merge all columns into a single column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-query-store

```
  id college1  college2  college3
   1 abc       xyz        rst
```

Above is the input-

Looking for output :-

```
id college1  college2  college3
 1  abc 
 1  xyz
 1  rst
```

Comment: Why does your result set have four columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is simply `union all`:

```
select id, college1 as college from t
union all
select id, college2 as college from t
union all
select id, college3 as college from t;
```

This requires scanning the table three times, which is usually fine.  But if "t" is really a complicated query or really big table, there are more efficient approaches.

Comment: thank you for the answer, this will work for the college column , but how to how get the id column

Comment: @user190549 . . . The result set has both `id` and `college`.